# How can I install requirements.txt from docker-compose?

Tags: python, django, docker, pip, docker-compose

I have created a dockerized django app using docker-compose(following [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) tutorial).
Now I want to add some packages to requirements.txt and install them.
What is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

From the tutorial you point to - the statement

`ADD requirements.txt /code/` copies `requirements.txt` file from your current directory on the host into `/code/` directory inside the container. When `docker-compose run` command is executed, it first builds the container at which point it loads the 'requirements.txt' file into it.

So if you want to make changes to it, do it locally before you run compose. This will build and run your dockerized app with the new packages in your modified `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: `ADD requirements.txt /code/` should be written in Dockerfile

Answer (score -1):

Go into your virtual environment. Your file name is `requirements.txt`

You need to type in the terminal

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This should install all the packages listed in your requirements.txt

In case when some of your modules failed to install you have to manually install them.

Comment: I think the best would be if docker could install via `pip` on `docker-compose run`.